# Recommend a design pattern/approach to exposing/tolerating/recovering from system errors, Exception handling (Java, C++, Perl, PHP)

Tags: design-patterns, exception, error-handling

Can you recommend a design pattern/approach to exposing/tolerating/recovering from system errors, Exception handling (Java, C++, Perl, PHP)?

Some errors need to be reported.

Some errors can be handled internally (by a retry or are inconsequential (can be ignored).

How do you structure the code to catch them?

But all errors need to be logged.

What best practises are there?

And for simulating them to be able to fully test components that are impacted by them?

General non-programming-language specific question applicable to several modern programming languages but would welcome example illustrations of patterns, approaches and philosophies in Java, C++, PHP and Perl.

Comment: Perhaps such a philosophical question would benefit from 'community wiki'.

Comment: Also asked here for wider software/programming discussion: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/109297/recommend-a-design-pattern-approach-to-exposing-tolerating-recovering-from-system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My philosophy involves **always attempting to catch errors where they happen**.  Things like global exception handlers make for a difficult debugging process.  Keep error handling as local to the site of the failure as possible.  Debugging is easier, and it avoids non-specific error reporting that tends to confuse and frustrate users.

In terms of logging, that's an implementation decision.  I usually have some reporting utility functions sitting around that I invoke whenever I detect an error condition.  Obviously you can vary the logging level such that certain serious errors are reported.  Similarly, if your application should exit with an error, do that as quickly as possible.

Simulation and testing are somewhat orthogonal.  To test your error-handling code completely, you should be able to write test cases that cause each error to occur.  It may involve contriving inputs or altering state.  If you errors are *not* dependent on inputs or interaction with external systems, then you should really consider whether that's a failure condition, or just an implementation bug that is sporadically triggered.

Comment: +1 Thanks Gian about keeping error handling as local as possible. Seems like the software industry hasn't quite grasped a decent philosphy because from time to time, as users of all manner of systems: kiosks, websites, phones, apps, we are presented with those useless error messages: "an error occurred", "a general error occurred", "an unknown error occured", "error -1 occured". I will leave the question open for a bit longer to invite others to contribute...

Comment: Accepted answer, you cover important areas: catch where they happen and fast, choosing appropriate logging, testing, and distinguishing between bugs and actual failures. This deserves the accepted answer on stackoverflow. Everyone: For answers that match this plus a little more detail and extras, see they question and answers on: programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/109297/